# c++, Voce - how to compile a project?

Tags: c++, linux

My problem is that I wanted to try out Voce, however I wasn't able to start a sample program. I had to tweak lots of things, and as I can see the only remaining barrier between me and Voce is the following error(hopefully):
whenever I compile the sample program, it compiles succesfully but then, when I would like to launch it it gives me the following error:

```
[Voce] Java virtual machine created
[Voce ERROR] The requested Java class: voce/SpeechInterface could not be found.  Make sure the class path correctly points to the Voce classes.
This is a speech recognition test. Speak digits from 0-9 into the microphone. Speak 'quit' to quit.
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f0824ffcbd2, pid=7537, tid=139672968279936
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_72-b15) (build 1.8.0_72-internal-b15)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.72-b15 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x651bd2]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /home/username/testAudio/folder/core or core.7537
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/username/testAudio/folder/enter code herehs_err_pid7537.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

This is the whole ouput.

Further information: I'm using Kubuntu as an OS(so Linux, basically).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is a `java` error, how are you running this.

Comment: Have you checked whether your class path includes the mentioned class? The error log says it all.

Comment: First of all, thank you all for the quick response. Much appreciated.
Secondly, I may be lame, but I don't know how I should do that.
Any advice regarding that?

As for how I run:
compilation:
g++ -o myapp -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/include/ recognitionTest.cpp -L /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/ -ljvm

run:
./myapp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I was able to fix this issue. 
I will post the solution in case anyone will experience the same issues:
I just had to edit the cpp files to match the location of the lib folder, because my program couldn't find it.